# "It is done" what is the sentence structure?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english, learning

It is done

Is "done" in the above sentence an adjunctive or a verb?

Or is it a simple past tense in passive form. If so why "is" is used.

Please clarify what is the structure of the sentence. This sentence grammatically doesn't make sense to me in terms.

Comment: Have you heard of a verb's principle parts?? Do, did, done//catch, caught, caught/freeze, froze, frozen//see, saw, seen Just a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to analyze *done* without more context. Without that, it is ambiguous.

Barring additional context, it could mean (and be) either of these:

1. It is done. (The task has been completed.)
   Here, *done* is the past participle of the verb *to do*. It is the verb being used adjectivally, which is why it is preceded by *is*.
2. It is done. (It is exhausted.) 
   Here, *done* is an adjective describing the spent or tired state of the thing. There are of course multiple senses of *done*, none of which correspond to the verb *to do* at all.

Comment: It's the first one. To put a context, let's say "I will let you know once it is done". The past tense of the verb do is "did" and is "to do" a verb? I think it's not. Please clarify. Thank you

Comment: @user360189 The expanded sentence doesn't do anything to clarify the context. *I will let you know once it is done* is just as ambiguous as *it is done*. All it does is add some more words to the start of the sentence. What is *it* and what does *done* mean? But if you mean the first of my two list items, then that's the list item that answers your question. It's the past tense of the verb *to do* being used adjectivally.

Comment: Let's assume someone has emailed and assigned a task and I replied with the sentence: OK I will let you know once it is done. Is it wrong to use this way?

Comment: @user360189 No, it's perfectly normal.

Comment: So the verb done in here is an adjunctive or past participle of do. My confusion is that the sentence is in simple present; hence, it can't be past participle. If not so then what is it? Grammatically how can I make such a sentence?

Comment: @user360189 It's both. It takes the form of one and the function of the other. Many verbs serve the same kind of adjectival function. At the most basic level, the grammatical form of the sentence is *it is [x]*. What *[x]* is doesn't matter in terms of the general analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an adjective meaning several things. For example, if you cook a turkey in the oven, after a few hours, it will be *done*, i.e. it will be *cooked*. As another example, if you make a big mistake, you are *done*, as in you are *fired*.

Comment: I'm referring to the first one here. To give a context, just say "I will let you know once it is done". The past tense of the verb do is did and as per your reply above I think "to do" is not a verb and done is not its past tense. Can you please clarify?